Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps, or guard the use with a 'mounted'check
I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to understand the fallowing error:
"Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps.
Try rewriting the code to not use the 'BuildContext', or guard the use with a 'mounted' check."
Here is my code:
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool _redirecting = false;
  late final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  late final StreamSubscription<AuthState> _authStateSubscription;

  Future<void> _signIn() async {
    try {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      await supabase.auth.signInWithOtp(
        email: _emailController.text.trim(),
        emailRedirectTo:
            kIsWeb ? null : 'com.example.app://login-callback/',
      );
      if (mounted) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text('Check your email for a login link!')),
        );
        _emailController.clear();
      }
    } on AuthException catch (error) {
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(error.message),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
      );
    } catch (error) {
      SnackBar(
        content: const Text('Unexpected error occurred'),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
      );
    } finally {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _authStateSubscription = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange.listen((data) {
      if (_redirecting) return;
      final session = data.session;
      if (session != null) {
        _redirecting = true;
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/account');
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _authStateSubscription.cancel();
    _emailController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Sign In')),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18, horizontal: 12),
        children: [
          const Text('Sign in via the magic link with your email below'),
          const SizedBox(height: 18),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _emailController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 18),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _isLoading ? null : _signIn,
            child: Text(_isLoading ? 'Loading' : 'Send Magic Link'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

I am using the 'mounted' check but I am still getting this error. The code is working as expected but I am still getting this error.

You need to check the mounted also in the catch blocks. Also you are using the SnackBars wrong there, try this:
  Future<void> _signIn() async {
    try {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      await supabase.auth.signInWithOtp(
        email: _emailController.text.trim(),
        emailRedirectTo:
            kIsWeb ? null : 'com.example.app://login-callback/',
      );
      if (mounted) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text('Check your email for a login link!')),
        );
        _emailController.clear();
      }
    } on AuthException catch (error) {
      if (mounted) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text(error.message),
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
          )
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (mounted) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('Unexpected error occurred'),
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
          )
        );
      }
    } finally {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }


Remove the async & await key word. Use :-
.then(){
enter code here

}
